# Is it possible to iterate over single Key-Value Pair in Python to print a value to a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key-value

first time asking a question on the forums and have not had luck with my particular issue while searching for an answer or a lead. I am a beginner at python if that means anything so any help is appreciated!
I am just trying to write a "Loot Generator" program for my TRPG.
I have figured out what I want the program to do with regards to how it compiles the list.
...

```
#LISTS for storing loot based on rarity : YELLOW (COMMON) , GREEN (UNCOMMON) , RED (RARE)
# BLUE (ULTRA) , PURPLE (MYTHIC)
YELLOW = []
GREEN  = []BlasterRifle =  { 'name' : 'Blaster Rifle'  , 'cost' : 350} 
RED    = []
BLUE   = []
PURPLE = []

# test Dictionary to represent an ITEM
BlasterPistol = { 'name' : 'Blaster Pistol' , 'cost' : 250}
BlasterRifle =  { 'name' : 'Blaster Rifle'  , 'cost' : 350}
```

The issue... every time it iterates over all 'data' points in ITEMS{} it prints the 'name' of the ITEM twice...

```
def lootMechanics(ITEM):
    for data in ITEM:
        if ITEM['cost'] == 250:
            YELLOW.append(ITEM['name'])
            

#prints out to a list in a certain format with no brackets.
print(*YELLOW , sep = ' , ')
```

the output becomes :

*Blaster Pistol , Blaster Pistol*
I just want the output to read
*Blaster Pistol*

Comment: Could you make it exact which part of the code behaves unexpectedly and what would be your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment due to not enough reputation.

The issue is your output is not an anomaly if the `ITEM` parameter of your `lootMechanism(ITEM)` function is a list of dict.

There is a bit of issue with your for loop with your `lootMechanism(ITEM)` function. I believe it is supposed to be:

```
def lootMechanics(ITEM):
    for data in ITEM:
        if data['cost'] == 250:
            YELLOW.append(data['name'])
```

If your `ITEM` list does include multiple dicts which meet the `if` condition in the `lootMechanism(ITEM)` function then you would get multiple same names.

If you do not desire such behavior then I would suggest you use a `set()` object to store the `'name'` property of the items.

Comment: I have never seen set() used before. I appreciate the help. I will look into this. I do plan to add more data than just the 'cost'. I was trying to get a test program working to build a bigger one off of.

Comment: @MrSeekz Sets are really great for storing unique datasets. If you do plan on storing other information, you could just store the entire dict object instead of just its name or other properties